# How to get list of playback processes in PulseAudio

Tags: linux, terminal, pulseaudio

How do I get the list of the playback processes that are currently monitored by pulseaudio control via terminal?

[image]

I wish to get the process names or pid of System sounds and gmusicbrowser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"System Sounds" doesn't have a process; it's a passive setting for... system sounds.

Everything else can be retrieved using `pacmd list-sink-inputs`.